# Do Dreamzzz sets include multiple builds?

Tags: sets

I've seen the [Dreamzzz](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Dreamzzz) sets, and I am curious if they generally include multiple builds per set. For example, here's a shot from the back of [Dream Village (40657)](https://brickset.com/sets/40657-1/Dream-Village):

[image: Back of box photo]

Is this a different build than the main model pictured on the front of the box? Are there separate instructions for this model?

Answer (score 5):

The Dreamzzz sets are not 2-in-1 sets in the same vein as sets such as Exotic Parrot from [Creator 3-in-1](https://rebrickable.com/sets/?theme=672) that include completely distinct builds using using the parts included in the set:

[image: Exotic Parrot]

However, they do tend to include a [choose your own adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_Your_Own_Adventure) element as part of the build. There is commonly a point in the build where the builder gets to decide between different paths that lead to somewhat different final models. Here's what this looks like specifically for Dream Village:

[image: Dream Village instruction fork]

In the case of that set, there are no new parts to add after this point. The choice is between assembling the six modular components created so far into a single large structure, or 3 smaller structures. In essence, each of the smaller building can split into a lower and upper story. If desired, these have connections points on certain edges that can allow them for form a larger structure:

[image: Sideways assembly]

This approach is common in the Dreamzzz line. Many of the larger sets include customization instructions after a barebones model has been completed. Here are the two included options for Stable of Dream Creatures:

[image: Stable of Dream Creatures box back]

Instructions are provided for these 2 styles, but the intent appears to be to demonstrate that there is opportunity for modification, adjustment, creativity and rebuilding with these sets.

Some sets go even farther than this by providing alternatives for significant portions of the build. [Fantastical Tree House](https://brickset.com/sets/71461-1/Fantastical-Tree-House) includes a pair of options:

[image: Tree House back]

These options may look similar at first, but they actually require building completely different modules:

[image: Option 1]

[image: Option 2]

The modules used in that set are the same basic size as those from the Dream Village, so there is opportunity to remix between different sets within the theme:

[image: Dream Village + Dream Treehouse]

Overall, these sets don't provide the same experience as true multi-build sets, but they do have additional build paths beyond a standard set.